# How to circumvent "code too large" error (Java)?

Tags: java, jena

I automatically produce a java class from a rdf file (with [schemagen](http://jena.sourceforge.net/how-to/schemagen.html)/jena). The class just contains constants, that is statements of the form

```
public static final Resource foo = m_model.createResource( "http://example.com/foo" );
```

The generated java class has a size of 930 KB, so it doesn't compile. Any ideas how to circumvent this problem? I could use just some part of the rdf file as input but it would be convenient to use the whole one.

Comment: Can you not break the class up and generate a set of classes with logically grouped subsets of the entries?

Comment: Is your vocabulary/ontology really that large? How many classes? How many properties?

Comment: It is a thesaurus modeled with skos. So these are all individuals.

Answer (score 1):

With that many constants, you are not going to use them all, so you can't really need to generate all of that class.

The limit you are running into is inherent to the format of a class file.  If you are going to continue generating classes, you have no choice but to partition the constants into multiple classes.

But I recommend that you generate text file that your program can read:

- It could be in Properties format so that you can load it into a Properties object.
- It could be SQL so that you can batch insert it into a database table.
- It could be any number of other formats ... including one of the RDF serializations.

Comment: You are right, I just need a couple of them. But it is very convenient when programming to have access to these constant via autocomplete. And when the rdf file changes then the new uri's are automatically reflected in the java class.

Comment: @EmanResu - Yea well ... maybe you should just generate constants for the RDF file "entries" that your code depends on, and forgo the auto-completion convenience.  As I said, the limit you are running into is hard-wired into the file format and the JVM / compiler toolchain.

Comment: @EmanResu - Thought ... there is NO LIMIT on the number / size of comments in a generated file.  You can't auto-complete against a comment, but IDE text search will work.